# Database Time Availability Representation

Tags: database

I'm just starting a project where I need to track employee availability.  Essentially each day is split into 5 periods and an employee may be available or unavailable for any period. In theory their availability may look like:

Mon1 - False

Mon2 - True

Mon3 - False

And so on.

I'm attempting to create a model that will handle this efficiently.  Is it better to make it more generic or have one row with all availability?

Option 1:

EmpFK | Day | Period | Availability

Option 2:

EmpFK | Mon1 | Mon2 | .... | Fri5

Either way it would be 25 rows or 25 columns which I feel seems overkill. Is there a more efficient way to represent this?

Comment: Tag only the database that you use.

Answer (score 0):

Of course that Option 1 is what you should do - it's called database normalization.
Just think about any statistic you'd like to have - like calculate running average availability in last 7 days or anything else with 25 columns per employee.

*) ...and you don't need to store both period states - just store either when employee is available or when is not available depending on your approach.

Comment: Ya I thought option one was normalized but was overthinking it. As the availability is used each week it's only set once. That makes sense to only store available times and infer the rest. This is to ensure constraints when assigning a time. The only other way I can think is instead of storing each individually, do a start | end and store groups of times i.e. mon1-tues3, thurs4-fri5 and so on.